# One-way repeated measures ANOVA with skewed response

Tags: r, repeated-measures, outliers, skewness, group-differences

We have an experiment with 102 individuals in total. We have an outcome $Y$ (which is a variable related to the structure of a given bone), and we want to know whether this variable $Y$ differs depending on sex. For most of the individuals (but not all), $Y$ was measured on both the left and right sides of the body, so that we have two measurements for each of these individuals. Thus, the goal would be to compare the means of $Y$ for females and males, taking into account the repeated measures when they arise.

Here is a subset of the data (in R):

```r
dtf <- structure(list(Y = c(1783.7, 1340.1, 1469.1, 659.7, 1669.9, 1424.3, 
791, 995, 1498.3, 1778, 1541.5, 902.6, 1276.9, 1235.7, 628.9, 
1179.2, 901.1, 1066.2, 1429.6, 765, 826, 672.1, 725, 1237.2, 
1279.1, 776.1, 1515.7, 696.1, 615, 375.4, 356.9, 385.5, 509.6, 
589.2, 596.1, 741.8, 5296.7, 1009.6, 644.8, 1027.9, 1023.8, 1081.2, 
1061.1, 1172.2, 824.6, 1008.9, 697.1, 6089, 3138.1, 480.3, 667.4, 
920.3, 753.4, 579.6, 719.5, 932.7, 660.5, 572.9, 446.7, 969.7, 
791.2, 985.5, 650.6, 642.4, 3695.7, 600.9, 367, 1080.5, 1129.3, 
623.4, 773.7, 1219.9, 1594.5, 625, 916.6, 718.4, 962.7, 837.4, 
822.4, 911.9, 1005.1, 1089.8, 1237.3, 1937.5, 1617.9, 1138.8, 
2030.9, 1783.5, 1017.9, 1050.4, 846.7, 349.6, 572.6, 664.8, 1412.5, 
770.3, 891.8, 783, 560.8, 449.2, 763.6, 710.3, 1152.6, 655.1, 
543.4, 861.7, 1023.7, 773.3, 657.2, 432.3, 625.4, 457.7, 1110, 
283.9, 459.2, 1763.2, 1190.5, 401.3, 549.4, 471.6, 555.7, 955.6, 
490.4, 682.4, 719.7, 1965.1, 328.5, 1197.5, 478.9, 470.9, 745.3, 
2779.4, 561.6, 731.4, 605.3, 591.6, 766.9, 547.9, 770.1, 1052.3, 
980.6, 1614.7, 1371.7, 452.8, 681.3, 439.7, 1207.5, 899.4, 506.1, 
536), ID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 
9L, 10L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 
19L, 19L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 23L, 23L, 24L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 28L, 
29L, 31L, 32L, 32L, 33L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 35L, 37L, 37L, 38L, 38L, 
39L, 39L, 40L, 40L, 41L, 41L, 43L, 43L, 44L, 44L, 45L, 45L, 46L, 
48L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 53L, 54L, 54L, 55L, 55L, 
56L, 56L, 57L, 57L, 58L, 58L, 59L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 61L, 62L, 62L, 
63L, 63L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 67L, 68L, 68L, 69L, 69L, 70L, 70L, 71L, 
71L, 72L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 75L, 76L, 76L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 79L, 
80L, 81L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 83L, 84L, 84L, 85L, 86L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 
89L, 90L, 91L, 91L, 92L, 92L, 93L, 93L, 94L, 94L, 95L, 96L, 96L, 
97L, 97L, 98L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 101L, 101L, 102L, 102L), levels = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", 
"25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", 
"36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", 
"47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", 
"58", "59", "60", "61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "66", "67", "68", 
"69", "70", "71", "72", "73", "74", "75", "76", "77", "78", "79", 
"80", "81", "82", "83", "84", "85", "86", "87", "88", "89", "90", 
"91", "92", "93", "94", "95", "96", "97", "98", "99", "100", 
"101", "102"), class = "factor"), Sex = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("F", "M"), class = "factor")), row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "5", "6", "7", "8", "11", "12", "13", "16", "19", "23", 
"24", "25", "26", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", 
"37", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "49", "52", "53", 
"54", "55", "60", "61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "67", "68", "71", 
"72", "73", "74", "75", "76", "77", "78", "79", "80", "83", "84", 
"85", "86", "87", "88", "90", "93", "94", "96", "97", "98", "99", 
"101", "103", "104", "105", "106", "107", "108", "109", "110", 
"111", "112", "113", "114", "115", "116", "118", "119", "120", 
"121", "122", "123", "124", "127", "129", "130", "131", "132", 
"133", "134", "135", "136", "137", "138", "139", "140", "141", 
"143", "145", "146", "147", "148", "149", "150", "153", "154", 
"155", "156", "158", "159", "161", "162", "163", "164", "165", 
"167", "168", "169", "170", "172", "173", "175", "177", "178", 
"179", "180", "181", "182", "183", "184", "185", "187", "188", 
"189", "190", "191", "192", "193", "195", "197", "198", "199", 
"200"), na.action = structure(c(`4` = 4L, `9` = 9L, `10` = 10L, 
`14` = 14L, `15` = 15L, `17` = 17L, `18` = 18L, `20` = 20L, `21` = 21L, 
`22` = 22L, `27` = 27L, `28` = 28L, `38` = 38L, `39` = 39L, `47` = 47L, 
`48` = 48L, `50` = 50L, `51` = 51L, `56` = 56L, `57` = 57L, `58` = 58L, 
`59` = 59L, `66` = 66L, `69` = 69L, `70` = 70L, `81` = 81L, `82` = 82L, 
`89` = 89L, `91` = 91L, `92` = 92L, `95` = 95L, `100` = 100L, 
`102` = 102L, `117` = 117L, `125` = 125L, `126` = 126L, `128` = 128L, 
`142` = 142L, `144` = 144L, `151` = 151L, `152` = 152L, `157` = 157L, 
`160` = 160L, `166` = 166L, `171` = 171L, `174` = 174L, `176` = 176L, 
`186` = 186L, `194` = 194L, `196` = 196L), class = "omit"), class = "data.frame")
```

```r
summary(dtf)
#>       Y                ID      Sex   
#> Min.   : 283.9   1      :  2   F:60  
#> 1st Qu.: 617.1   3      :  2   M:90  
#> Median : 791.1   4      :  2         
#> Mean   : 998.3   7      :  2         
#> 3rd Qu.:1136.4   13     :  2         
#> Max.   :6089.0   16     :  2         
#                  (Other):138
```

Thus, in R, the idea would be something similar to the following model:

```r
library(car)
library(lme4)
mod <- lmer(Y ~ (1|ID) + Sex, data = dtf)
Anova(mod)
```

However, the outcome $Y$ is quite skewed, and has some strong outliers, as you can see here:

```r
library(lattice)
densityplot(~ Y, groups = Sex, data = dtf)
```

[image: density plot]

As expected, the residuals of the model are not so good. Thus, it looks like the data do not meet the assumptions of a classic, parametric repeated measures ANOVA.

What would be some correct alternatives in the case of a skewed outcome with strong outliers like here?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us some graphs of the data?

Comment: You could generate ranks, then transform ranks into percentiles ($pct$), and then input percentiles into the inverse cumulative normal function to get z-scores, $Z_i=\Phi^{-1}(pct)$, and then input the z-scores.  Or just use ranks - which we have done before and published on.

Comment: I'd opt for a different conditional distribution that accomodates some large values. Personally, I'd start with a Gamma distribution. This can be fit using the `gamlss` package: `gamlss(Y~Sex + random(ID), data = dtf, family = GA())`.

Comment: The use of ranks or normal scores doesn’t work in general (e.g., if you want to test an interaction between two variables).  I’d use a semiparametric ordinal regression model with random effects.  See [here](https://fharrell.com/post/rpo) for resources.  Best performing method will be a Bayesian random effects ordinal model as with the R `rmsb` package or `brms` package.